# How large is the Linux kernel compared to Unix?

Tags: linux, byte

Not in just LOC (lines of code), but in storage size, as in bytes, megabytes, gigabytes, etc.

Also, any sources where I can download the original-based Unix OS? Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: Start here to look up what you are looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix. Then reformulate your question. Now, it's like: "*Where could I get this Microsoft Stuff*". Step 2: Get the newest kernel here: https://www.kernel.org/ and be aware that it is zipped. Step 3: Proceed to step 1

Comment: I don't need _steps_. I specifically asked a question, and expected that answer herein.

Comment: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#rtfm

Comment: This question is meaningless: there's no such thing as “the original-based Unix OS”, there were many versions.

Comment: I downloaded Linux kernel version 3.12.3 (stable) from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/). The tar.xz version weighed in at 72.8mb which yielded 484mb uncompressed. Version 3.10 is [said](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) to have 15,803,499 lines of code. Zzz.

Comment: @illuminÉ and now compare it to what? ;)

Comment: @chirp Don't know, [illumos](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate)? Zipped 150mb, uncompressed 535mb. Just meaningless numbers really...

Comment: also, for the future, saying things like "[I] expected that answer herein" is likely to make people annoyed at you. people on Stack Exchange freely volunteer their time, and they expect you to do at least basic research before you ask a question. @chirp was giving you steps to do that research.

Comment: Linux is only a kernel, this is why you cannot compare it even to a specific UNIX variant. UNIX sources contain the kernel, libraries and commands

Comment: 144MB of source files, 4 million lines of code: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/understanding-the-linux/0596002130/apc.html

Answer (score 1):

It is really unclear, what you are asking.

Yes, you can count LOC in the Linux kernel, but you cannot in any commercial UNIX.
Therefore it is not really possible to compare those.

What do you mean with "storage size"? You can download the Linux kernel from kernel.org. You can look at the compressed size, you can unpack it and look at the size of the complete source code, you can build a kernel in many different ways to build a tiny kernel containing only the bare minimum or a huge one containing pretty much every possible feature. - What size are you interested in?

[There is not a single UNIX](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Unix_history-simple.svg), to compare with. There are free Unices like (Free|Open|Net)BSD, and there are also a bunch of commercial ones. There is really no way for a meaningful answer to your question.

Comment: doesn't *Unices* refer to *Unix-like* in terms of: behaves like UNIX. There is a *Single UNIX Specification* (http://www.unix.org/online.html) that defines what must be "aboard" to call it UNIX OS. I think the word "*Unices*" could be misleading - especially for beginners or "outsiders". In the worst case it could lead to: "*Linux is UNIX, only free*" being considered a correct answer... ask some lawyer(s) about this ;)

Comment: @chirp will it seems that SCO once for all asked the lawyers a couple of years ago.... ;)